# AngularJS route syntax error illegal character

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I am trying to add a new page to my website ( it was developed by somebody else ) and when I add another block to the route I just get an error like:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module nameApp due
>   to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'nameApp' is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
>   module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/nomod?p0=nameApp

My routing config:

```
 .config(
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
        {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                title: 'Home',
                controller: 'HomeController',
                reloadOnSearch: false
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
                reloadOnSearch: false

            })
             .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/404' });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }
    )
```

I do not have any problems with this configuration as it loads ok in the Web Browser, but when I'm trying to add:

```
.when('/donate', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/donate.html',
    reloadOnSearch: false
    })
```

I receive the above error. ( I have also created the **donate.html** file )

**index.html**

```
<li>
    <a ng-class="getClass('/')" title="Home" href="/">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a ng-class="getClass('/about')" title="About Us" href="/about">About Us</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a ng-class="getClass('/donate')" title="Donate" href="/donate">Donate</a>
</li>
```

Any help about what is this happening and how could I get rid of that error ? As a mention, when I receive that error, the webpage looks like a mess.

Comment: Where do you define `nameApp`?

Comment: In the same js file. The problem is when I add that new page. Otherwise the website is ok

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error that prevents Angular from creating the `nameApp` module.

Comment: There are no syntax errors as I double checked

Comment: Can you paste the non-working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it done. This has nothing to do with angular but with nginx. Let's go deeper and tell you what happened:

I am using this flow in order to have my projects done: **Ubuntu 12.04**, **nginx**, **PHP-FPM**

Nginx has a **sendfile** directive, which defaults to on. It allows nginx to use the Linux kernel’s `sendfile()` operation to read the requested file from disk. This is typically quicker than using `read()` and `write()`. So far, so good.

The problem is that **sendfile** doesn’t work so well in virtual environments. The fix turned out to be insanely simple – just **turn sendfile off**. As it’s a development machine, the performance hit incurred by turning off this feature is pretty negligible. (It would want to be a pretty significant performance hit to outweigh the file truncation!)
In the nginx config http server block, I added:

`sendfile off;`

Once nginx was restarted, I was getting served full static files, and all was well with the world again!